# How to render a circular vignette with GLSL

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I’m trying to achieve a circular vignette with GLSL, but the result is elliptical when the texture is rectangular. What is the correct way to make it square regardless of the texture size? The input texture size (resolution) can be both rectangular or square.
I tried a solution using the **discard** method, but this doesn't suit what I require, as I need to use **smoothstep** to get a gradient edge.

Current result:

[image]

GLSL shader:

```
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

vec4 applyVignette(vec4 color)
{
    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution) - vec2(0.5);           
    float dist = length(position);

    float radius = 0.5;
    float softness = 0.02;
    float vignette = smoothstep(radius, radius - softness, dist);

    color.rgb = color.rgb - (1.0 - vignette);

    return color;
}

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
    color = applyVignette(color);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to respect the aspect ration when you calculate the distance to the center point of the circular view:

```
float dist = length(position * vec2(u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y, 1.0));
```

Note, if you have a rectangular viewport, where the width is greater than the height, then a perfect circle is squeezed at it left and right to an ellipse, when the coordinates are transformed from view space the normalized devices space.
You must counteract this squeezing by scaling up the x axis of the distance vector.